# 2 Business Rules calling at the same time when incident created

Tags: servicenow, servicenow-rest-api

I am facing an issue in servicenow Business rules. I have 2 business rules which has to trigger when

- When an incident created
- When specific fields of an incident updated

While creating an incident I'm setting some default values say **State - closed**, **Urgency - Low**. I am expecting that it should only trigger **create incident business rule** but it's triggering **update incident business rule** as well to set Urgency and State values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using `current.update()` in your Business Rule that runs on *insert*? If so, that is probably triggering the second Business Rule to run.

Also, make sure your Business Rule is set as a **before** Business Rule instead of an **after** to help the flow if at all possible.

It's generally not necessary to call `current.update()` for a **before** Business Rule since these run before the actual *insert* happens.

Take a look at the best practices for Business Rules when you have some time https://hi.service-now.com/kb_view.do?sysparm_article=KB0540192

In particular this one may describe the behavior your are seeing.

> **Best Practice #2**: Avoid using current.update() in before or after
>   business rules.  Avoid using current.update() to prevent recursions
>   that impact system performance. The current.update() triggers business
>   rules to run on the same table for insert and update operations. In a
>   before or after business rule, this can lead to the rule calling
>   itself over and over again.
>
> It is unnecessary to use current.update() in a before business rule
>   since these are saved automatically when the database is updated.
>   After business rules are not intended to update current objects, so
>   this is also not needed.
>
> Unless there is a special case, avoid using current.update()since it
>   not only stops business rules, but it also prevents the workflow
>   engine from running on the record.